# Combine two arrays values with identical field count (Into an Object?)

Tags: php, arrays

I want to combine two arrays:

```
$fields = array("Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4");

$values = array("Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4");
```

What I need to obtain is:

```
$combined = array (
 [0] = array("Field 1", "Value 1"),
 [1] = array("Field 2", "Value 1"),
 [2] = array("Field 3", "Value 3"),
 [3] = array("Field 4", "Value 4")
)
```

Or if its possible:

```
$combined = array (
 [0] = array(['name'] => "Field 1", ['value'] => "Value 1"),
 [1] = array(['name'] => "Field 2", ['value'] => "Value 1"),
 [2] = array(['name'] => "Field 3", ['value'] => "Value 3"),
 [3] = array(['name'] => "Field 4", ['value'] => "Value 4")
)
```

---

I hope you can help me out with this,

Thanks to all!

Comment: `$c = count($fields); $combined = array(); for($i = 0; $i < $c; $i++) { $combined[] = array('name' => $fields[$i], 'value' => $values[$i]); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fields = array("Field 1", "Field 2", "Field 3", "Field 4");
$values = array("Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4");

if (count($fields) == count($values))
{
    $newArray = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < count($fields); $i++)
    {
        $newArray[] = array('name' => $fields[$i], 'value' => $values[$i]);
    }

    // do what you want with your $newArray
}
```